# auto generate Rest service in node.js

Tags: rest, node.js, express, mongoose

Is there a way to auto generate a Rest service in node.js like in rails?
I just want to expose my mongodb models as a Restfull service. I am now doing a lot of repetitive work with Mongoose and express-resource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js REST framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099389/node-js-rest-framework)

Comment: not a duplicate, I am asking for a framework with specific capabilities

Comment: Alright, well at least look at the links there.  I suspect it is a fairly comprehensive list of what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's possible, follow this commands:

```
npm install railway
railway init rest-app && cd rest-app && npm install
railway generate scaffold resource property1 property2
railway server 3000
```

That's it!
If you need to generate nested resource:

```
railway generate resource.nestedresource propertyForNestedResource
```

and modify config/routes.js:

```
map.resources('resource', function (res) {
    res.resources('nestedresources');
});
```

Check this example app: https://github.com/anatoliychakkaev/railway-example-app

Welcome to railway: http://railwayjs.com

Comment: looks promising, however I have some issues using it on windows. Is it supported? The first issue was that I can only activate "node railways" from its local folder. After this the scaffold always tries to recreate existing folders (e.g. app) so I get "file already exists" error on generators.js:520:16

Comment: I never tried it on windows, but I know few win-guys in our community. Feel free to ask any questions in google groups, I think they will happy to help you :) We have very friendly community :)

Comment: Stable release 1.0 planned soon, I think we need add more love for windows installation, your feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a library I developed if Railway is too bulky for your needs:

https://github.com/enyo/mongo-rest

It's a simple library, well tested, that just provides a REST interface for your mongoose models.

Comment: Hi @enyo/@tknew, I looked at Mongo-Rest and it looks pretty cool, but it appears (based on a cursory reading of the docs) to be missing some pretty basic but important stuff. I don't want to be too quick to write it off if I've missed something. It looks like I can't easily turn on/off certain routes (e.g. GET, POST, no PUT, DELETE) for certain models, nor do they allow me to easily permission models (in the simplest case, ensuring that e.g. only authenticated users can PUT/POST/DELETE). Am I missing anything? Thanks!