# Where are some good examples displaying dynamic data within Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, html-rendering

I'm working my way through displaying various data elements from parent & child data, with repeating data, paged, data, etc. I was wondering what the best sites are with tutorials or other information related to this. I'm working on this primarily with Express.js, Jade and would like to primarily stick to those, maybe using additional tools like knockout.js or backbone.js if reasonable.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general node.js purpose, I find http://howtonode.org/ very informative, up to date.

For express.js I think, Their documentation is good, and there are few articles on http://howtonode.org/ about Express.js. This question contains many good resources about how to use express.js [Learning Express for Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144214/learning-express-for-node-js).

I am not able to figure out what you meant by, parent & chlid data, repeating data. Assuming you meant, JSON services for data stored in Mongodb.

- RailwayJS framework is allowing auto-generation (scaffolding).
  [auto generate Rest service in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096237/auto-generate-rest-service-in-node-js).
- A simple web service tutorial
  http://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-simple-webservice-in-nodejs

If you are looking for more specific resources, please provide detailed information.